# Wrapping a class method?

Tags: ruby

I have a module I'd like to be able to wrap every method in a class, whether it be an instance method or a class method, but am having a bit of trouble trying to get it to work in both circumstances. Below is what I have right now, it works for wrapping instance methods but calling class methods doesn't seem to work. I assume the module proxy isn't installed correctly for overriding class methods, but I'm not sure what to do to fix that.

I'm limited to ruby 2.7, btw.

```
module Wrapper
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    module Proxy
    end

    def wrap_method(name)
      puts "wrapping #{name}"
      Proxy.define_method(name) do |*args|
        puts "in wrap_method, about to call #{name}"
        super *args
      end
    end

    def wrap_methods
      # wrap any methods that were defined before this was called
      self.instance_methods(false).each {|name| wrap_method(name) }
      self.singleton_methods(false).each {|name| wrap_method(name) }

      # wrap any methods that are defined after this is called
      self.class.define_method(:singleton_method_added) do |name|
        if respond_to?(:wrap_method)
          wrap_method(name)
        end
      end
      self.class.define_method(:method_added) do |name|
        if respond_to?(:wrap_method)
          wrap_method(name)
        end
      end
      self.prepend(Proxy)
    end
  end
end

module Top
  module Second
    class Main
      include Wrapper

      wrap_methods

      def self.first_class_method
        puts "in self.first_class_method"
      end

      def self.second_class_method
        puts "in self.second_class_method"
      end

      def some_instance_method
        puts "in some_instance_method"
      end

    end
  end
end

Top::Second::Main.first_class_method
Top::Second::Main.second_class_method
Top::Second::Main.new.some_instance_method
```

Output:

```
wrapping first_class_method
wrapping second_class_method
wrapping some_instance_method
in self.first_class_method
in self.second_class_method
in wrap_method, about to call some_instance_method
in some_instance_method
```

Comment: I think the issue is that `Proxy.define_method` just defines an instance method. To define a class method you would use `Proxy.singleton_class.define_method`. Possibly you want to pass another argument into `wrap_method` to indicate whether it's an instance or class method that should be defined.

Answer (score 1):

You prepend Proxy to the class itself, and this modifies the method resolution for instances of the class, but not for the class itself.

To achieve the second, you have to

```rb
self.singleton_class.prepend(Proxy)
```

in addition.